# Iterating over file directory in reverse in order to find latest file

Tags: c++

I have a directory full of files, each named according to the day it was created in YYYYMMDD format, ensuring that they are numerically ordered from least to most recent. I need to read only the most recent file that was not created today. My code for it has been this:

```
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::experimental::filesystem::v1;

path dirPath("C:/Logs/");
path recentPath;
string todaysDate("20170806"); // Or whatever the current date is, gotten automatically

for (auto it = directory_iterator(dirPath); it != directory_iterator(); it++)
{
    auto p = it->path();
    auto base = p.stem();
    auto ext = p.extension();

    if (ext == ".log" && base != todaysDate)
    {
        recentPath= p;
    }
}
```

This works since the iterator goes over the directory in an alphanumeric order. However, according to the documentation of `directory_iterator`:

> The iteration order is unspecified, except that each directory entry
>   is visited only once.

So my main issues here are:

1. This code is not guaranteed to work, since the specs don't always guarantee the same type of implementation
2. I have to go through all the old files in order to reach the latest one.

Is there a way that I could reach the file I need faster, and/or in a guaranteed way?

Comment: Lexicographically sort the output from the `directory_iterator` first.

Comment: Re: guaranteed. Just compare `p.stem()` with `recentPath.stem()`, and only update `recentPath` if the former is greater than the latter. Re: faster - I don't think so.

Comment: If there are so many files over time that they become a performance issue, the classic solution would be to store the files in a directory tree, for example, `storage_root/YYYY/MM/filename`